# Column 'studentID' in field list is ambiguous?

Tags: sql

I want to join the query to get the rank against the mark from two table against the same student ID.

What's wrong in my query?

```
SELECT 
studentID, 
mark,  
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*)+ 1 
    FROM 
        ca B 
    WHERE 
        A.mark < B.mark
) AS Rank 
FROM 
ca A INNER JOIN mark on ca.studentID = mark.studentID
ORDER BY 
mark DESC
```

Comment: Specify table-name/alias.studentID in the select list. (And the same in the ORDER BY.)

Comment: there are 2 columns known as "studentid", so use the alias **CA.studentid** , ..... because there is more than one column of the same name it is "ambiguous" until you choose one by the relevant alias

Comment: Your `rank` column can be calculated easier using the `rank()` window function. No need for an expensive co-related subquery

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Is `mark` in the table `mark` or `ca`?

Comment: See above, "Please tag your question with the database you are using". Regretfully downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is the missing table aliases on the columns.  This can confuse SQL.  And, we don't want to confuse SQL.  So, use qualified column names.

Also, I am guessing that the column `mark` is actually in the table `mark`, not `ca`.  This just seems logical to me.  I make this assumption below, but it is easy enough to switch the logic back to `ca`.

Most databases support ANSI standard window functions.  In such databases you can use the much simpler:

```
select a.studentId, m.mark,
       rank() over (partition by a.studentId order by m.mark) as rank
from ca a join
     mark m
     on a.studentID = m.studentId
order by m.mark;
```

I should note that you don't even seem to need the `join`, because `studentId` is in both tables.  So, this is likely equivalent:

```
select m.studentId, m.mark,
       rank() over (partition by m.studentId order by m.mark) as rank
from mark m
order by m.mark;
```

If you don't need the `join`, that also fixes your version with the subquery.  But, table aliases are still a good idea:

```
SELECT m.studentID, m.mark,  
       (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 
        FROM mark m2
        WHERE m.mark < m2.mark
       ) AS Rank 
FROM mark m
ORDER BY m.mark DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this line in your code:

```
INNER JOIN mark on ca.studentID = mark.studentID
```

**studentID** is a column name in 2 tables (ca and mark)

Because there are 2 of the same name, using just the column name by itself is said to be "ambiguous". Imagine a room of people at an office party, two of those have the name Paul. If you yell "Paul" across the room, is it clear which Paul you are trying to attract?

So: always use your aliases to make sure your queries avoid ambiguity

```
SELECT
      A.studentID
    , mark.mark
    , (
            SELECT
                  COUNT(*) + 1
            FROM ca B
            WHERE A.mark < B.mark
      )
      AS Rank
FROM ca A
      INNER JOIN mark ON A.studentID = mark.studentID
ORDER BY
      mark.mark DESC
```

It's also worth pointing out that you have used the alias A against table ca

```
FROM ca A
```

so, because there is an alias (A) you must now use that alias and NOT the table name (ca)

however, for the other table (mark) you have not declared an alias, so you use the table's name instead of an alias e.g.

SELECT **A**.studentID , **mark**.mark